# TransctionBuilder.new() in cardano-serialization-lib 10.0.0

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib

With the new version of library TranasctionBuilder.new() arguments have changed.

When running:

```
    const txBuilder = this.S.TransactionBuilder.new(
      this.S.LinearFee.new(
        this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.linearFee.minFeeA),
        this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.linearFee.minFeeB)
      ),
      this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.minUtxo),
      this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.poolDeposit),
      this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.keyDeposit),
      this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.coinsPerUtxoWord),
      protocolParameters.maxValSize,
      protocolParameters.maxTxSize,
      protocolParameters.priceMem,
      protocolParameters.priceStep,
      this.S.LanguageViews.new(Buffer.from(languageViews, "hex"))
    );
```

It throws an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'new')
```

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably now use the ConfigBuilder to create a config for creating the TransactionBuilder.

This should do the trick:

```
const cfg = TransactionBuilderConfigBuilder.new()
      .fee_algo(this.S.LinearFee.new(
        this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.linearFee.minFeeA),
        this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.linearFee.minFeeB)
      ))
      .pool_deposit(this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.poolDeposit))
      .key_deposit(this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.keyDeposit))
      .max_tx_size(protocolParameters.maxTxSize)
      .max_value_size(protocolParameters.maxValSize)
      .coins_per_utxo_word(this.S.BigNum.from_str(protocolParameters.coinsPerUtxoWord))
      .build()

const txBuilder = this.S.TransactionBuilder.new(cfg);
```

Comment: It worked out. Thank you.

Comment: the TransactionBuilderConfigBuilder is not part of @cardano/serialization-lib-asmjs .. does anyone know why ?

Comment: Just checked and it should be there. Maybe double check the version you have installed. It must be one above 10.0.0 - try installing the latest (which is currently 10.2.0) via: npm i @emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-asmjs@latest